# Passing get-parameters doesn't work in WebPages

Tags: c#, vs-web-application-project, asp.net-4.6

first site:

```
<a href="employees.cshtml?department=management">Employees</a>
```

second site:

```
Request.Params["department"]
```

But the get-parameter doesn't get passed from the first site to the second.

can't figure out the mistake. Please help!

No MVC, No Webforms!
Empty ASP.NET 4.6 Web Application Template!

Comment: The last line is very confusing.  What *are* you using, if not webforms or MVC?

Comment: @Amy i created a project via visual studio: visual c# -> Web -> ASP.NET 4.6 Webapplication -> selected template: Empty ("an empty project template for creating ASP.NET applications. This template does not have any content in it."). Than Added new item -> razor -> web page (razor v3)

Comment: You're using razor views without MVC?  o_O  That isn't going to work.

Comment: wish i could post a picture,  but yes